# リリース済みアプリのiOS Certificates, Provisioning filesの削除について

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, iphone

リリース済みアプリの、Certificates, Provisioning filesの有効期限を延長するために、Developer Center上で、既存のものを削除し、新しく作成し直しました。

しかし、この作業によって、リリース済みアプリの起動ができなくなったという報告があがってきました。既存アプリへの影響はないという認識だったのですが、違うのでしょうか？　もし対応策などあれば教えていただけないでしょうか？　下記は起動できないアプリに表示されるログとなります。

`<Error>: Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1314b3330; <Bundle Idenfier>; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID <Bundle Idenfier>" UserInfo={BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job,`

Answer (score 0):

もう一度 [iOSアプリのCertificate(証明書)の更新方法 - mattsuDev’s blog](http://mattsudev.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/09/30/152037) のような手順で [怖くないiOSの証明書 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/bl-lia/items/c6ec88020d526cdb454c) や Apple の技術情報を参考にしながら証明書とプロファイルを作成してみてはどうでしょう。

> リリース済みアプリの起動ができなくなったという報告

これはテスト端末にインストールしてあったアプリでしょうか。古いプロファイルを削除してはいけなかったのかもしれません。